# Python - save requests or BeautifulSoup object locally

Tags: python, file, beautifulsoup, scrape

I have some code that is quite long, so it takes a long time to run.  I want to simply save either the requests object (in this case "name") or the BeautifulSoup object (in this case "soup") locally so that next time I can save time.  Here is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'SOMEURL'
name = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(name.content)
```

Comment: You might find the [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) module useful ...

Comment: What about just saving `html` source code into the `html` files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since `name.content` is just `HTML`, you can just dump this to a file and read it back later.

Usually the bottleneck is not the parsing, but instead the network latency of making requests.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://google.com'
name = requests.get(url)

with open("/tmp/A.html", "w") as f:
  f.write(name.content)


# read it back in
with open("/tmp/A.html") as f:
  soup = BeautifulSoup(f)
  # do something with soup
```

Here is some anecdotal evidence for the fact that bottleneck is in the network.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time

url = 'https://google.com'

t1 = time.clock();
name = requests.get(url)
t2 = time.clock();
soup = BeautifulSoup(name.content)
t3 = time.clock();

print t2 - t1, t3 - t2
```

Output, from running on Thinkpad X1 Carbon, with a fast campus network.

```
0.11 0.02
```

Comment: FYI, you can replace `BeautifulSoup(f.read())` with just `BeautifulSoup(f)`.

Comment: I have no idea why this response is either accepted or has 8 upvotes. I have just tried it and it is not working. Namely, when trying to f.write(name.content) it returns "TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes". Of course, because the type of the Response.content object is byte not html.

Comment: Probably this was working in earlier version of requests, but in version 2.26.0 this method of writing requests object in a file is not working and the reason is that name.content is byte type not text.

Comment: Perhaps change `f.write(name.content)` to `f.write(str(name.content))`. The former is byte but the latter is a string.

Answer (score 1):

### Storing requests locally and restoring them as Beautifoul Soup object latter on

If you are iterating through pages of web site you can store each page with `request`  explained here. 
Create folder  `soupCategory` in same folder where your script is.

Use any [latest user agent](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/the-latest-user-agent/chrome) for `headers`

```
headers = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0 Safari/605.1.15'}

def getCategorySoup():
    session = requests.Session()
    retry = Retry(connect=7, backoff_factor=0.5)

    adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
    session.mount('http://', adapter)
    session.mount('https://', adapter)

    basic_url = "https://www.somescrappingdomain.com/apartments?adsWithImages=1&page="    
    t0 = time.time() 
    j=0    
    totalPages = 1525 # put your number of pages here        
    for i in range(1,totalPages):         
        url = basic_url+str(i)
        r  = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        pageName = "./soupCategory/"+str(i)+".html"
        with open(pageName, mode='w', encoding='UTF-8', errors='strict', buffering=1) as f:
            f.write(r.text)        
            print (pageName, end=" ")
    t1 = time.time()
    total = t1-t0
    print ("Total time for getting ",totalPages," category pages is ", round(total), " seconds")
    return
```

Latter on you can create Beautifoul Soup object as @merlin2011 mentioned with:

```
with open("/soupCategory/1.html") as f:
  soup = BeautifulSoup(f)
```